# How many ways are there for the average of the two course grades to be a positive integer?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm working on this homework problem (in quotes):

> "Let $M$ and $A$ denote the final grades in math and in algorithmics. Both grades are between $0$ and $20$ and we suppose that they have integer values. Assuming that both modules have the same coefficient (weight), a student tries to determine the number of combinations of $A$ and $M$ which may result in a global average equal to $k \in \{1, \ldots, 20\}$. How can you help this student?
> You may, for example, represent the situation with a $2$-entries table."

I'm just making sure we want to solve the following problem:
For a given  $k \in \{1, \ldots , 20\}$, find the number of possible solutions to $(m,a)$ so that:
$m \in \{0, \ldots , 20\},\ a \in \{0, \ldots , 20\},\ m + a = 2k.$

(1) Is this the correct formulation of the problem?

(2) If yes, then how do we go about solving them? I'm also not sure what they meant by "2-entries table."

Answer (score 1):

For any given $k \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $1 \leq k \leq 10$, $m$ must be some element in $\{0,1,2,\cdots,2k\}$.  Therefore, for each such $k$, the number of possible ordered pairs $(m,a)$ is $(2k+1)$.

For any given $k \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $11 \leq k \leq 20$, $m$ must be some element in $\{2k - 20, 2k - 19, \cdots, 20.\}$.  Therefore, for each such $k$, the number of possible ordered pairs $(m,a)$ is $[(20 + 1) - (2k-20)] = 41 - 2k$.

Here, if $k = 2$, I am distinguishing between (for example) $(m,a) = (3,1)$ and $(m,a) = (1,3).$

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure why $m$ should be $2k$ for any given $k?$ For example, if $k=12,$ then $m$ can't clearly be $24.$

Comment: @LearningMath +1 (also) : good catch; my mistake.  Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

Brute forcing this (i.e. go through all $21^2$ combinations of $(m,a)\in\{0,...,20\}^2$ and tally up the answer) is likely feasible, but tedious and would not work on an exam, especially if the professor chooses anything much higher than 20.

An alternative approach would be as follows: for each *fixed* $a\in\{0,...,20\}$, how many $m$ in $\{0,...,20\}$ satisfy $m+a=2k$? Call that number $n_a$. After you determine $\{n_a\}_{a=0}^{20}$, calculate $\sum_{a=0}^{20} n_a$. Note that you could go through each $a\in\{0,...,20\}$ one by one, but this may not be necessary. (Hint, what if $a$ is even? odd?)

Other (more elegant approaches) are surely possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your formulation of the problem is not correct.  Observe that if $m = 18$ and $a = 20$, then $m + a = 38 > 20$.  Also, since we want $\frac{m + a}{2} \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 20\}$, we cannot permit $m = a = 0$.

A $2$-entries table is a table with, say, the possible values of $m$ on the horizontal axis and the possible values of $a$ on the vertical axis.  You could then write $(a, m)$ as the entry in the $m$th column and $a$th row.  The entries you seek are those in which $m + a$ is even and $m + a \neq 0$.

However, it is not necessary to build such a table.  You have correctly concluded that the average of the mathematics and algorithmics scores will be an integer if and only if the sum of the scores is even.

When is the sum of two integers even?  The two addends must have the same parity, meaning they are both even or both odd.

In how many ordered pairs $(m, a)$ are both entries odd?  In how many such pairs is $\frac{m + a}{2} \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 20\}$?

In how many ordered pairs $(m, a)$ are both entries even?  In how many such pairs is $\frac{m + a}{2} \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 20\}$?

Can you proceed?